# Get User for Audit Entries

Tags: sql-server, audit

I am trying to construct history entries for my application tables.  (Basically a "who changed what and when" set of tables.)

My problem is that I have a lot of users.  Well over a thousand.  My users use UI applications that then call services.  The users authenticate to those services using OAuth2 and Open Id Connect (OIDC).  So I can't use "Integrated Security" to access SQL Server.  Instead I access SQL Server using a service account.

This means a call to `SUSER_NAME()` will return the service account instead of the user.

I have thousands of SQL queries.  It will be A LOT of work to go change each one to add a user parameter.

I am really hoping there is some way I can pass the real user to SQL Server.  I know this does not work, but an example would be something similar to adding it to a header in a call.

**Is there some way to get the user to SQL Server besides the logged in user?**

Or, failing that, is there some way to get SQL Server to work with access tokens (OAuth and OIDC)?

Comment: Have you tried using `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` function ?

Comment: @KinShah - The problem is that my users do not have a login on the system.  It is always just the system account.  To the actual user that is causing the action never logs into the SQL Server.

Comment: @LowlyDBA - I like the way that idea is going.  Most of my developers use connection pooling.  So I will need a way change the Application Name for an existing connection.  I will look into the possibility of that.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the application is setup, one (maybe the only?) way to pass data at the connection level would be to utilize the [ApplicationName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.applicationname?view=netframework-4.8) portion of the connection string.

You could have the application set this value based on the logged in user, making it accessible via [`APP_NAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/app-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on the database side.

Example:

```
Server=myServer;User Id=myUsername;Password=Pass;ApplicationName="MyApp - User LowlyDBA"
```